# discord.py: run bot for the first time, got "discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed."

Tags: python, discord.py

I have created a discord client, but unable to login, because of improper token.

I have tried to regenerate the token and use the new one, but to no avail.

```
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in')

client.run(DISCORD_SELFBOT_TOKEN, bot=False)
```

This code worked in my previous user, but I have deleted the user, so now I am setting it up again.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This depends entirely on the value of `DISCORD_SELFBOT_TOKEN`, which is obviously a secret.  It sounds like you're using a bot account, why not try logging in with the email/password combination of the account you're logging in with?

Answer (score 0):

`bot=False` is for only running self-bots which is against Discord TOS, and you have to use a user account token to run.

If you're using a bot token to run it, then remove the `bot=False` parameter and make sure that your bot token is actually the correct bot token